# Can't get to the login screen

Tags: windows-8

I upgraded my wife's Windows 7 machine, to Windows 8 Pro, about 10 days ago. She's been using it fine ever since.

We typically leave our desktops running 24/7, and just turn off the monitor. This morning she turned the monitor on, and saw the screen with the Seattle Space Needle, and then she pressed the enter key to get to the login screen.

Nothing happened.

Next she pressed the mouse key.

Nothing happened.

The mouse moves around fine. But we can't get it past the Seattle Space Needle screen. She replaced the batteries in both her keyboard and mouse recently. So, what's going on? How do we fix it?

Comment: If pressing the ESC or Enter key does not get you to the enter password screen, you might want to press the power button or sleep button. Power management runs as a driver so it is usually able to perform the actions even when the UI is stuck. You can then start/wake up your computer and see if it has recovered. If not, you may have to force the power down and start hunting for incompatible drivers and/or applications.

Comment: Does the screen "bounce" a little when you click the mouse? I've found that have have to "throw" the lock screen up to get to the sign in screen. If it doesn't then try @billc.cn advice above.

Comment: I've got some additional info. We decided to just to a hard boot, which brought it back up. After it came up again, it complained about some Windows updates failing and rolled back. After my wife logged in we changed the update history and found the following Windows Updates that failed:

 

KB2785094

KB2779768

Comment: K.A. the screen didn't bounce at all, when clicking the mouse, before we did a hard boot.